# Incompatible types, found scanner required boolean

Tags: java

I am trying to return a Boolean control that I get from the user for a loop in my main block though this function. I keep running into the error "incompatible types Require: boolean Found: Scanner". Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(Sting[] args){
    do { 
        ....
    } while(again());
}

public static boolean again(){
    System.out.println("Do you want to do this again? Enter Yes or No");
    return (new Scanner(System.in))next().equalsIgnoreCase("yes");
}
```

Comment: Methods require a `.`

Comment: It is always the little things... Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You need a dot preceding `next()`:

```
return new Scanner(System.in).next().equalsIgnoreCase("yes");
```